# Working with @font-face rule

Tags: html, css, google-fonts

```
div h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Exo 2 Light'), local('Exo2-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/exo2/v4/TZlHHgxEfHXA7uKM1eaCjXYhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Exo 2'), local('Exo2-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/exo2/v4/mJrGVjHbrdshrbGyvd7vdaCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

I am trying to use a google font I also have it linked in my html file as follows:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
```

Unfortunately after I added the font style the text does not show up. Is there something wrong with how I'm doing it?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: First of all, try adding the font-face options at the top of the page. Secondly if you use google fonts you could easily @include them (see: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/#article-header-id-4)

Answer (score 0):

As described in the google font website, when you have included the link tag, you have to specify the font

> Specify in CSS
>
> Use the following CSS rules to specify these families:

```
font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
```

> For examples of how fonts can be added to webpages, see the getting started guide.

So in your  css you'll just have to add:

```
.someSelector {
   font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your browser doesn't support woff2 fonts